# add suffix based on multiple conditions from string values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-conditions, suffix

I would like to add a suffix to strings in one column when a condition is met in another column. If a value is present in "Market" column, "Symbol" column corresponding value is updated to include current ticker but I would like to add a suffix to it representing its market place. I guess I could create multiple masks and change multiple values with multiple lines of codes for each value but I was wondering if there exist a more elegant way of doing this in one operation.

This is what I tried :

```
conditions = [ (df['Market'].str.contains("Oslo")), (df['Market'].str.contains("Paris")), (df['Market'].str.contains("Amsterdam")), (df['Market'].str.contains("Brussels")), (df['Market'].str.contains("Dublin"))   ] 
values = [str+'.OL', str+'.PA', str+'.AS', str+'.BR', str+'.IR'] 
df['Symbol'] = np.select(conditions, values)
print(df)
```

I get an error :

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'type' and 'str'

any help welcome

added after KingOtto's answer...
the data frame :

```
|  Name             | Symbol   | Market                 |
|:------------------|:---------|:-----------------------|
|  1000MERCIS       | ALMIL    | Euronext Growth Paris  |
|  2020 BULKERS     | 2020     | Oslo Børs              |
|  2CRSI            | 2CRSI    | Euronext Paris         |
|  2MX ORGANIC      | 2MX      | Euronext Paris         |
|  2MX ORGANIC BS   | 2MXBS    | Euronext Paris         |
|  5TH PLANET GAMES | 5PG      | Euronext Expand Oslo   |
|  A TOUTE VITESSE  | MLATV    | Euronext Access Paris  |
|  A.S.T. GROUPE    | ASP      | Euronext Paris         |
|  AALBERTS NV      | AALB     | Euronext Amsterdam     |
|  AASEN SPAREBANK  | AASB     | Euronext Growth Oslo   |
|  AB INBEV         | ABI      | Euronext Brussels      |
|  AB SCIENCE       | AB       | Euronext Paris         |
|  ABATTOIR         | -        | Euronext Expert Market |
|  ABC ARBITRAGE    | ABCA     | Euronext Paris         |
|  ABEO             | ABEO     | Euronext Paris         |
```

The code to create a new df with a suffix column and then merge these values with the symbol column to obtain a ticker correctly understood by Yahoo Finance to be queried.

```
suffix_list = pd.DataFrame({'Market': ['Euronext Growth Oslo','Euronext Expand Oslo', 'Oslo Børs', 'Euronext Brussels','Euronext Growth Brussels','Euronext Paris', 'Euronext Access Paris','Euronext Growth Paris', 'Euronext Lisbon', 'Euronext Access Lisbon', 'Euronext Dublin', 'Euronext Growth Dublin', 'Euronext Brussels', 'Euronext Access Brussels','Euronext Amsterdam'], 'suffix':['.OL','.OL','.OL','.BR','.BR','.PA','.PA','.PA','.LI','.LI','.IR','.IR','.BR','.BR','.AS']})
new_df = pd.merge(df, suffix_list, how='left', on='Market')
new_df['Ticker']=new_df['Symbol']+new_df['suffix']
```

The new dataframe containing the Ticker column:

```
|  Name             | Symbol   | Market                 | suffix   | Ticker   |
| :-----------------|:---------|:-----------------------|:---------|:---------|
|  1000MERCIS       | ALMIL    | Euronext Growth Paris  | .PA      | ALMIL.PA |
|  2020 BULKERS     | 2020     | Oslo Børs              | .OL      | 2020.OL  |
|  2CRSI            | 2CRSI    | Euronext Paris         | .PA      | 2CRSI.PA |
|  2MX ORGANIC      | 2MX      | Euronext Paris         | .PA      | 2MX.PA   |
|  2MX ORGANIC BS   | 2MXBS    | Euronext Paris         | .PA      | 2MXBS.PA |
|  5TH PLANET GAMES | 5PG      | Euronext Expand Oslo   | .OL      | 5PG.OL   |
|  A TOUTE VITESSE  | MLATV    | Euronext Access Paris  | .PA      | MLATV.PA |
|  A.S.T. GROUPE    | ASP      | Euronext Paris         | .PA      | ASP.PA   |
|  AALBERTS NV      | AALB     | Euronext Amsterdam     | .AS      | AALB.AS  |
|  AASEN SPAREBANK  | AASB     | Euronext Growth Oslo   | .OL      | AASB.OL  |
|  AB INBEV         | ABI      | Euronext Brussels      | .BR      | ABI.BR   |
|  AB INBEV         | ABI      | Euronext Brussels      | .BR      | ABI.BR   |
|  AB SCIENCE       | AB       | Euronext Paris         | .PA      | AB.PA    |
|  ABATTOIR         | -        | Euronext Expert Market | nan      | nan      |
|  ABC ARBITRAGE    | ABCA     | Euronext Paris         | .PA      | ABCA.PA  |
|  ABEO             | ABEO     | Euronext Paris         | .PA      | ABEO.PA  |
```

Comment: please provide an explicit example of data (as text)

Comment: @mozway I promise to get better at asking questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to proceed in 3 steps

1. You need to define an exhaustive suffix_list - a dictionary that holds information only once for each market

   `suffix_list = pd.DataFrame({'Market': ['Oslo', 'Paris'], 'suffix':['OL','PA']})`
2. You want to merge the `suffix_list` into your existing dataframe as a new column - one command for all markets (for each market that has a suffix in the list, you add that suffix):

   `pd.merge(df, suffix_list, how='left', on='Market')`
3. Now that you have the 2 columns `'value'` and `'suffix'` next to each other for all rows, you can apply 1 single operation for all rows

   `str('value')+'suffix'`

Comment: Thanks @KingOtto but that was my question. There are no easy way to this all at once? I don't have a column with suffix_list unless I run multiple conditions to populate it.

Comment: You need to define a single list only once: `suffix_list = pd.DataFrame({'market': ['Oslo', 'Paris'], 'suffix':['OL','PA']})` Then `pd.merge()` is a single command to add all the suffixes for all the markets to all the rows - done!

Comment: I think there is a misunderstsanding - getting this 'suffix_list' into the dataframe is in fact a single command for all rows - that's the core of my reply. I edited above to make more clear

Comment: Just use the lines of code above.. It is in fact a working example. The 'suffix_list' dictionary uses the exact same suffix as you have used in your question, the column is called 'Market' (with capital 'M'), so merging should also work). If you copy/paste, it answers the question according to the structure  you put in your question

Comment: 'df['Yahoo Ticker'] = df['Yahoo Ticker'].replace(['Euronext Growth Oslo','Euronext Expand Oslo', 'Oslo Børs', 'Euronext Brussels','Euronext Growth Brussels','Euronext Paris', 'Euronext Access Paris','Euronext Growth Paris', 'Euronext Lisbon', 'Euronext Access Lisbon', 'Euronext Dublin', 'Euronext Growth Dublin', 'Euronext Brussels', 'Euronext Access Brussels','Euronext Amsterdam', ],['.OL','.OL','.OL','.BR','.BR','.PA','.PA','.PA','.LI','.LI','.IR','.IR','.BR','.BR','.AS'],regex=True)'

Comment: Thanks @KingOtto

Comment: Thinking back, this is really a hack and does not solve the topic for people coming here wishing to add a suffix to a string in one column based on values in another column. I guess one could build a list of unique values for the conditions and use them in a conditional loop to make the replacements. I still think there is a less tedious approach that someone might share eventually.

Comment: Zen4attitude, that is exactly what we are doing above... Have you actually tried the above in your console?? From a mathematical-philosophical approach, I am pretty sure it does not get simpler other than (1) define each suffix for each market exactly once, (2) apply a vector operation to all markets in a single step... how do you want to solve that quicker. and please, try the above.. does it fix your problem? then please accept the answer. does it not do the job? then kindly explain what else you are missing?

Comment: Thanks to @kingotto for his royal patience. It works.